# Setting Background image in mail content using php

Tags: php

I would like to know how we can set the background imange in mail content using php. Currently I have sending e-mail php code but it has not background image.
Hope everyone can help me.

Best Regards,

Ponomy

Answer (score 1):

You probably know this already, but you'd also use CSS for the actual background and not set it on an HTML or body tag, best practices for HTML email are to use a div as the container for all your HTML and set the CSS background property inline like this:

```
<div style="background: url("http://www.mimoymima.com/wp-content/themes/mym5/images/bkg_fade_grass_home.png");">
```

NOTE that the url uses HTTP, you can't use a relative path to an image.

brent
@
mimoymima.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your mail as html in order to get backgrounds/etc.  To do so you have to add the background image as an attachment.  See [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php), under sending html email.  Remember though, not all clients support html in their emails.